# how to pass arguments to "psutil.Process().as_dict" items such as cpu_percent(interval = 1)?

Tags: psutil

I love you all as my brothers and sisters.

I was searching on psutil, suddenly a question came to my mind that:
   " How is that possible to send arguments to items of as_dict attrs?"
for example in following code we want to ask psutil to return cpu_percent  with its interval argument set 1:

```
import psutil,sys
p= psutil.process_iter()
for process in p:
    try:
        pinfo=process.as_dict(attrs=['pid','name','num_threads','cpu_percent'])
        if pinfo['name']=='svchost.exe':
            print pinfo
    except Exception as ex:
        print ex
```

in default cpu_percent() interval is None. How to pass a different interval value to as_dict method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Simply use the original method directly instead of going through as_dict()